# What is the best method of measuring hdd status on a server?

Tags: command-line, server, 14.04, hard-drive

I have a brand new server in place that is running 14.04. This is acting as our web server for hosting multiple Moodle sites for nearby school districts.  I don't have the GUI installed.  I need to make sure I can accurately determine and resolve any potential hdd failure.  I have four 1TB drives in RAID10, run by a Megaraid controller.  Is there a particular package I can install or a command I can add to my cron to check for potential issues and email alerts?

Answer (score 1):

What comes to my mind quickly is you can install Nagios with its plugins to monitor vital statistics of the server. I strongly recommend you install Nagios on a separate server within your network.

I remember you can

1. Monitor Hard Disk - Space, Temperature
2. RAM
3. Network Traffic
4. It can also monitor certain processes
5. Email Alerts

If nagios is not a possibility, you can install OCS Inventory (sudo apt-get install ocsinventory-server) on a separate machine within your network and install a ocsinventory client on the web server. (sudo apt-get install ocsinventory-client). First the server and then the client.

With this you can monitor the server's entire hardware and software inventory. Email alerts may not be possible with this. But a browser based health check of the server can be seen quite quickly sitting in the network.

Good luck. Let me know if you use something else.

For OCS Inventory - follow [http://wiki.ocsinventory-ng.org/index.php/Documentation:Main](http://wiki.ocsinventory-ng.org/index.php/Documentation%3aMain)

For Nagios follow - http://techsupport1978.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/nagios-open-source-it-infrastructure-monitoring-solution/

Regards